# Splitting of normal bundle exact sequence and Holomorphic neighbourhood retract

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $Y\subset X$ a complex submanifold of $X$.
Consider the two following conditions:

1. The exact sequence  $0\to TY\to TX|_{Y}\to N_Y\to 0$, where $TX$, $TY$ denote the holomorphic tangent bundle of $X$ and $Y$ and $N_Y$ denotes the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$, splits as an exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles on $Y$.
2. There is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $Y$ in $X$ which holomorphically retracts onto $Y$ i.e., there exists a holomorphic map $r:U\to Y$ such that $r|_{Y}=id_Y$.

It is known that $2\implies 1$. What about the implication $1\implies 2$? Are there examples $X$ and $Y$ where $1$ does not imply $2$?